# How to run UWP app as Kiosk in Windows 10 Home Edition

Tags: windows, shell, uwp, kiosk

I have a Windows Universal UWP app that I want to launch as a replacement shell on Windows 10 Home.

Typically for Win32 apps this is to set HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon\Shell to the appropriate EXE.

I have configured the UWP app with an execution alias in the Package.appxmanifest

```
      <Extensions>
    <uap5:Extension
      Category="windows.appExecutionAlias"
                Executable="App1.exe"
      EntryPoint="App1.App">
      <uap5:AppExecutionAlias>
        <uap5:ExecutionAlias Alias="App1.exe" />
      </uap5:AppExecutionAlias>
    </uap5:Extension>
  </Extensions>
```

I have also overridden App.OnActivated() to launch the application with this:

```
    protected override void OnActivated(IActivatedEventArgs args)
    {
        switch (args.Kind)
        {
            case ActivationKind.CommandLineLaunch:
                {
                    CommandLineActivatedEventArgs cmdLineArgs =
                    args as CommandLineActivatedEventArgs;
                    CommandLineActivationOperation operation = cmdLineArgs.Operation;
                    string cmdLineString = operation.Arguments;
                    string activationPath = operation.CurrentDirectoryPath;
                    Frame rootFrame = Window.Current.Content as Frame;

                    if (rootFrame == null)
                    {
                        rootFrame = new Frame();
                        rootFrame.NavigationFailed += OnNavigationFailed;

                        Window.Current.Content = rootFrame;


                        rootFrame.Navigate(typeof(MainPage),
                        string.Format("CurrentDirectory={0}, Arguments={1}", activationPath, cmdLineString));
                        Window.Current.Activate();
                    }
                }
                break;
            default:
                {
                    Frame rootFrame = Window.Current.Content as Frame;

                    if (rootFrame == null)
                    {
                        rootFrame = new Frame();
                        rootFrame.NavigationFailed += OnNavigationFailed;

                        Window.Current.Content = rootFrame;

                        rootFrame.Navigate(typeof(MainPage),
                        string.Format("CurrentDirectory={0}, Arguments={1}", Environment.CurrentDirectory, string.Empty));
                        Window.Current.Activate();
                    }
                }
                break;
        }
    }
```

Running App1.exe from command line works properly.

However placing the App1.exe registry: Shell='App1.exe'

does not launch the app (screen stays black on login.

I assume this is possible, because if I set Shell='Skype.exe'
Which is the execution alias for the Skype UWP app, skype launches properly on login.

I am searching for the missing piece of the puzzle.

** EDIT 2/14/21 **
So, I *think* the issue is that UWP apps are hosted in the explorer.exe application and if that is not running it, the app will never be able to run.  Either that or it primes the UWP framework somehow.

I think Skype is likely a Hosted UWP app: [Created Hosted apps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/hosted-apps)

So what I have done is make a standard Win32 application that launches explorer.exe and quickly cripples it before it can display anything by implementing a keyboard hook to prevent Windows Key and other potential shortcuts, and also hiding the taskbar.  Then starting the UWP app.

Its a little bit hackish, so I  have not posted it as the solution, hoping that a cleaner one still is posted

Comment: Could you please tell me whether the **Shell** in your case means **Windows PowerShell**?

Comment: Shell refers to the registry setting for the default shell. If this is not supplied the default shell is explorer.exe

Comment: Any news about a better solution? I am facing the same issue. Would a hosted UWP app solve the issue? Why didn't you go that route? Would still like to see the hack if nothing else is available.